# Why do we still need external synchronization when a synchronizedList() or Vector is already synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, synchronization, thread-safety

ArrayList is not synchronized. But there's a way the get a synchronized one as mentioned in `java.util.ArrayList`'s JavaDoc:

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(...));
```

In `java.util.Collections` JavaDoc you can read that "**It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned list when iterating over it:**"

```
synchronized(list) {
    Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
    while (i.hasNext())
    foo(i.next());
}
```

Using a synchronized ArrayList results in additional work, why not use a
`java.util.Vector` instead? Is there an advantage in using this approach?

I found this question on [http://www.coderanch.com/](http://www.coderanch.com/t/422977/java/java/synchronizedList-Vector) and I'm sharing its great answer here from the same post.

Comment: IMHO that the construction is not working has always been obvious. I wonder(actually I wondered when I was a kid and saw it for the first time :-)) why Java engineers designed Vector as it is at all. There was no clear memory model that days, so I'm not sure if synchronized was giving any benefits.

Comment: @BorisTreukhov The benefit was mutual exclusion.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Actually it turned out that there was no alternative to Vector http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282627/why-vector-in-java-has-to-be-synchronized - hence its nothing-to-do-with- synchronization name `Vector`, the same story with the `Hashtable` . `ArrayList` and `HashMap` were added in JDK 1.2

Comment: @BorisTreukhov That's well-known. I thought you wondered why Java's original collections were synchronized.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In java.util.Collections JavaDoc you can read that "It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned list when iterating over it:"

If you are doing multiple transactions on a list (like iterating across it), then a synchronized list will not protect you from a `ConcurrentModificationException`.  There is still the possibility that someone will add or remove to the list while you are iterating across it and that will throw.

The `Collections.synchronizedList()` protects the list against concurrent operations from multiple threads.  In the case of the iterator, you are making list calls but then returning to your code and then making list calls again.  Even though the methods are synchronized, you are not protected against the race conditions of other threads operating on the list in the meantime.

> Using a synchronized ArrayList results in additional work, why not use a java.util.Vector instead? Is there an advantage in using this approach?

`Vector` is not going to help here.  It will also throw an exception under the same circumstance.  To quote from the javadocs:

> The Iterators returned by Vector's iterator and listIterator methods are fail-fast: if the Vector is structurally modified at any time after the Iterator is created, in any way except through the Iterator's own remove or add methods, the Iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException.

Also, `Vector` is a very old class.  It is widely held that it is better to use a synchronized `ArrayList`.

Here's a couple of things that you can do:

- You can copy the list into another collection which you then can iterate across.  Even if other threads add or delete from the synchronized list, your local collection is safe.  This doesn't protect you from modifications to the elements of the list of course.
- You could switch to a fully concurrent collection such as `ConcurrentHashMap` (it's not a list of course), that handles modifications to the collection while you are iterating.  `ConcurrentSkipList` or `LinkedBlockingQueue` are other choices.
- As @Geek points out, [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) is another option although the performance depends a lot on the ratio to iterating and writing.

Comment: [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) might be useful here depending on the ratio of traversal to write operations.